# How to merge folders while renaming the files within them them in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-management

Right now I have a folder that contains subfolders numbered 1-600. Within each of these subfolders is a collection of around 20 images that are all numbered starting from 001. I want to merge these subfolders into one big folder which would have all of the images with their numbering along with the number of the folder they are in as well (for instance the 6th image in the 145th folder might be named something like "(145) 006". Is there any way I can do this on windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

 Rename the files while moving them to the root folder:

```
$Root = 'c:\RootFolder'
( Get-ChildItem $Root -File -Recurse ) |
    Move-Item -Destination { ('{0}\({1}) {2}' -f $Root, $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name ) }
```

To remove empty folders:

```
gci $Root -dir -recurse | ? { -not (gci $_.FullName -force) } | Remove-Item
```